# How do I do something like a motion tween in OpenGL on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, shapes, tween, motion

I'm very new to OpenGL and programming with a graphical element in general.

Currently I have a texture that is mapped using vertices that are generated by another part of the code -- these four points that represent the corners change a few times a second.  As it is implemented, this image will jerkily 'appear' in different places and shaped differently as the four corner points are altered on the timer.

What I would like to have happen is for the object to quickly move and change shape to occupy the new points given by the program -- and I would like for this to happen somewhat smoothly (so it would kind of float between these supplied positions/shapes).

Is there any way to do a kind of motion/shape tween like that in OpenGL?  If so, where can I find documentation or, better yet, examples?  I'm having trouble finding or understanding this kind of thing.

EDIT:  ALSO - I have no problem using another method, it doesn't need to be OpenGL.  Is this better done in Core Animation with BasicAnimation?  If so, where are some resources for this kind of transformation?  The shapes are quadrilaterals but not necessarily squares or rectangles so I would need the ability to specify each corner point.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL provides no such facility.

The part of the code that generates the vertices, can't that be modified to smoothly transition the positions rather than abruptly changing them? If not, can you write code on top of that code, and that code you write wraps the position generation by smoothly transitioning?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I didn't even think of simply writing code to get intermediate points.. I don't know why it didn't occur to me!

Is this kind of functionality available in other places like Core Animation though?  Perhaps I need not use OpenGL at all?  I'm just worried about overhead and causing the app to lag -- it's doing a LOT of work as it is right now.

Comment: I don't know anything about Core Animation, but if you have code that is giving you one point and then later giving you a completely different point, you just need to interpolate between those two points. It's pretty basic stuff (find the difference between the two, decide how much you want of that difference you want to add to your first point per frame, add it to the first point, and keep adding until you reach the second point [some number of frames later])..